# meteor.js 1 dimensional isomorphic hash

Tags: node.js, collections, meteor

new to `meteor` and `node` in general. I'm trying to create a global hash that would be isomophic, change in either server or client would update both. Using nosql db's i think is overkill as I only need the one record. So I was thinking that if I declared a hash that was open to both server and client that it would be isomorphic whilst my app was running, but non persistent.

Seems I was wrong. Is there any way to do this, without using databases, nosql or sql?

My filestructure:

```
$ tree ./
./
├── client
│   ├── main.css
│   └── main.html
├── collections
│   └── corpus.js
├── public
├── server
└── myApp.js
```

I'm declaring the initial state of the hash (`corpus`) in: `collections/corpus.js`:

```
var Corpus = {
    raw: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    words: []
}
```

`myApp.js`:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.body.helpers({
        corpus: function () {
            return Corpus.raw
        }
    })
}
```

`main.html`:

```
...
        <div id="main" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="corpus-update">
                    <input name="text" value="{{corpus}}">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for https://github.com/BenjaminRH/meteor-user-session

They are session variables which can be set on the server if you specify the userId too

Comment: Seems that requires `meteorite` to be installed. I was looking for solution more native to meteor

Comment: `meteor add benjaminrh:user-session`